# "false" appearing next to ob_start()

Tags: php, codeigniter, output-buffering, ob-start, ghosts-in-the-machine

I appear to have a ghost. I'm loading a page (normally loaded inside another page, if that helps, but the bug still appears when I load the page by itself) and at the top of the output, before everything else, I get a random `false`.

It is output during `$this->load->view('my_view');`. I went and investigated the CodeIgniter system files and found, within the `_ci_load($_ci_data)` method, a line that says `ob_start();`. When I put lines around this code like this:

```
echo "hey!";
ob_start();
echo "here!";
```

the output I get is `hey!falsehere!`.

The only way I've found that I can stop the `false` from being output is by putting another `ob_start()` somewhere before that in the code. I've fiddled with different placements, in the controller, the view, the view loader, and in CodeIgniter.php itself. Here's where I found it breaks:

```
// Is there a "remap" function? If so, we call it instead
if (method_exists($CI, '_remap'))
{
    $CI->_remap($method, array_slice($URI->rsegments, 2));
}
```

If I put `ob_start()` before the call to `_remap`, the `false` goes away; if I put it right afterwards, the `false` still shows up.

Anyone know what to do? I know this is a really hard and obscure question, but I have no idea what the next step I should take is. Any recommendations of where the problem could possibly be coming from are very much welcome.

I'm running PHP 5.4.30, using CodeIgniter 2.1.4 (probably time to update ...)

Comment: If the `false` is being output by the `_remap` method, maybe look at what the method does. I'm guessing there is a `echo` or `print` somewhere that is being called on a boolean variable.

Comment: i would update to 3.0 and stop messing with the system files

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, I looked at the _remap method and all it does is call call_user_func_array on my controller method. So I thought perhaps it was because I had an old version of PHP, but updating to 5.6 didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was deep inside a model called by another model called by the controller that was outputting a `false` when a certain error condition happened. Moral of the story, search deeper into my own code instead of blaming it on a bug in the framework ...